# Word processor with infinite page feature

Tags: word-processor

I would like to use a WYSIWYG word processor, like Word, Google Docs, Pages or LibreOffice Writer, with this feature: infinite page size.

By that I mean that the document is not divided into pages, intended for print. Instead, **the page just continues forever, the way a web page does**.

I frequently write documents that are never intended to be printed, and I have to deal with the inconveniences of page breaks, when I do not need page breaks to be there in the first place. Anyone know of a word processor that has this? Also, which file format does it save in?

Comment: You've already named it: at least LibreOffice supports that mode, simply switch to "web view" from its menus :)

Comment: Word too supports the webView. Also note that the Online version of word available at https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx is in this mode by default. So you can try out this functionality without even installing anything.

Comment: Almost every word processor that I know has the __option__ to view the document this way, _usually under the view menu_, LibreOffice can read & save a multitude of formats and is __free__.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost all modern word processors have this as an option.  For some examples:

- In Google Docs - Select `View` and un-tick `Page Layout`
- Word 2010 - On the `View` tab select `Web Layout`
- LibreOffice Writer - `View` - `Web Layout`

All produce the required results - i.e. no page breaks.